# MVC datepicker - Not changing value after postback

Tags: jquery, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a datepicker and setting the default value to last month as:

```
   $(".dateFrom").datepicker('setDate', '-1M');
```

Once the page is loaded it displays the default date. and allows user to select other dates.

If the user selects the date, I want to display that date else I have to display setdate.

Is there a way to overwrite set date?

Any input on this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The value of the datepicker should be in your model to be persisted. 
On the load of the view, put the value of the model in a hidden field or in a javacript variable.
Then use that value to set the date of your datepicker. 
I hope it's clear.

Comment: Mathieu Labrie Parent                                            In the view, I have <div class="input-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { @class = "form-control dateFrom" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="datepickericon3">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>.

Comment: dateFrom is overwriting the original value

Comment: Manage the dateFrom server side. If it's new put Now() - 1 month and if it's not keep the value entered by the user.